# Accumulate ids to make a single ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, debouncing

I have multiple places where I need to make ajax requests to fetch the items corresponding to some ids. However, I only want to make a single request by accumulating these ids and debouncing the actual method that makes the ajax request...So far I've come up with this code, but it just feels ugly/non-reusable.

Is there any simpler/recommended method to achieve similar results without sharing `resolve`/`promise` variables like I did here?

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln9vazgp/3/)

```js
const fakeData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'baz'
  }
];

let idsToFetch = [];

let getItemsPromise, resolve, reject;

const fetchItems = _.debounce(() => {
  console.log('fetching items...');
  const currentResolve = resolve;
  const currentReject = reject;

  // simulating ajax request
  setTimeout(function() {
    const result = idsToFetch.map((id) => fakeData.find(item => item.id == id));
    currentResolve(result);
  }, 400);

  getItemsPromise = resolve = reject = null;
}, 500);

function getItems(ids) {
  idsToFetch = ids.filter((id) => !idsToFetch.includes(id)).concat(idsToFetch);
  if (!getItemsPromise) {
    getItemsPromise = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
      resolve = _resolve;
      reject = _reject;
    });
  }

  fetchItems();

  return getItemsPromise
    .then((res) => {
      return res.filter((item) => ids.includes(item.id));
    })
}

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('first request start');
  getItems([1]).then(res => console.log('first result:', res));
}, 100);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('second request start');
  getItems([1, 2]).then(res => console.log('second result:', res));
}, 200)
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('third request start');
  getItems([1, 3]).then(res => console.log('third result:', res));
}, 300)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Questions like this where code is working and you are looking to optimize are better suited to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll check there too, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it simpler to write a `debounce()` function with behaviour fully under my control rather than rely on a library method.

In particular, I went out of my way to engineer a different debounce behaviour from that in the question, by which (if I understand correctly) the first, and possibly *only*, request of a quick sequence must wait for the debounce delay to expire.

In the code below, instead of the original `getItemsPromise` a `debouncePromise` is used to signify a debounce period, during which fetching is suppressed and request data is allowed to accumulate. From the quiescent state (whenever `debouncePromise === null`), the next `fetch()` call will fetch data ASAP (next tick). Only second and subsequent calls are debounced, until the debounce period expires and the `debounce()` instance returns to its quiescent state. I think that is as valid a "debounce" paradigm as the original, and arguably better. (If not, then `fetch()` can be lightly modified to give the original behaviour).

Apart from that, differences are minor :

- messy externalized `resolve` and `reject` are avoided
- in an attempt to keep `debounce()` generic, a `resultsFilter` function is passed in addition to a `fetcher` and `delay`.

Further comments in code.

```
function debounce(fetcher, resultsFilter, delay) {
    let idsToFetch = [],
        debouncePromise = null;
    function reset() { // utility funtion - keeps code below clean and DRY
        let idsToFetch_ = idsToFetch;
        idsToFetch = [];
        return idsToFetch_;
    }
    function fetch(ids) {
        idsToFetch = idsToFetch.concat(ids.filter(id => !idsToFetch.includes(id))); // swapped around so as not to reverse the order.
        if (!debouncePromise) {
            // set up the debounce period, and what is to happen when it expires.
            debouncePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(resolve, delay);
            }).then(() => {
                // on expiry of the debounce period ...
                debouncePromise = null; // ... return to quiescent state.
                return fetcher(reset()); // ... fetch (and deliver) data for all request data accumulated in the debounce period.
            });
            // *** First call of this debounce period - FETCH IMMEDIATELY ***
            return Promise.resolve(reset()).then(fetcher); // (1) ensure fetcher is called asynchronously (as above). (2) resultsFilter is not necessary here.
        } else {
            return debouncePromise.then(res => resultsFilter(ids, res)); // when debouncePromise exists, return it with chained filter to give only the results for these ids.
        }
    }
    return fetch;
}
```

Sample usage :

```
function fetchItems(ids) {
    const fakeData = [
        { 'id': 1, 'name': 'foo' },
        { 'id': 2, 'name': 'bar' },
        { 'id': 3, 'name': 'baz' },
        { 'id': 4, 'name': 'zaz' }
    ];
    if (ids.length > 0) {
        return new Promise(resolve => { // simulate ajax request
            setTimeout(resolve, 400);
        }).then(() => {
            return ids.map(id => fakeData.find(item => item.id == id));
        });
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve([]);
    }
}
function filterResults(ids, results) {
    return results.filter(item => ids.includes(item.id));
}

// ******************************************************
let getItems = debounce(fetchItems, filterResults, 500);
// ******************************************************

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('first request start');
    getItems([1]).then(res => console.log('first result:', res));
}, 100);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('second request start');
    getItems([1, 2]).then(res => console.log('second result:', res));
}, 200);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('third request start');
    getItems([1, 3]).then(res => console.log('third result:', res));
}, 300);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('fourth request start');
    getItems([1, 4]).then(res => console.log('fourth result:', res));
}, 2000);
```

**[Tested to the extent of this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtq3jqky/)**

Comment: Nice, thank you for taking the time to address this. If I'm not mistaken, you've implemented throttling not debouncing, is this correct?

Comment: I think my paradigm is essentially the same as yours except for that initial request in every "debounce period", which is allowed through immediately. I don't know, does that make it throttling? Both versions accumulate request data during a dead period then make a single request with the accumulated data pool. For me, if your original version debounces then so does mine. Maybe someone else has a view.

Comment: It's not about the initial request, check the difference between the results of your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/amrnn/v2h4eurw/1/) and my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/amrnn/gvfew4u0/2/)...yours will fetch each 200ms between requests, while mine waits until there are no requests for 200ms and then fetch...yours implements throttling not debouncing (which I think is more appropriate for this use case anyway).

Comment: Our two versions are certainly different. It's largely academic but I'm not convinced that mine doesn't conform to the definition of debouncing given in the lodash documentation.  And I can't quite work out why, with a debounce constant of `200`, your version should wait until all four `getItems()` calls are made before issuing the first and only request. I'm cross-eyed from looking at the code. Hopefully it will come clear tomorrow.

Comment: Actually if you use `_.throttle` in my code instead of `_.debounce` you'll get similar behavior to your code [check this](https://jsfiddle.net/amrnn/gvfew4u0/4/). If we have a delay of 200ms then `debounce` will keep waiting as long as the time between each request is less than 200ms. However, `throttle` will fetch **every** 200ms as long as there are new request...the difference between them is a bit confusing.

Comment: Ah OK, with that explanation, it's all making more sense now. Thank you.

Comment: @AmrNoman, from your comments and having read [this](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/), I am persueded that my paradigm is much closer to "throttle" than to "debounce". Amazing what one can learn by trying to answer a question!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to somehow encapsulate the logic by creating a function generator that holds the previous two functions like this:

```js
   const fakeData = [{

      id: 1,
      name: 'foo'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'bar'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'baz'
    }
  ];

  function makeGetter(fetchFunc, debounceTime = 400) {
    let idsToFetch = [];

    let getItemsPromise, resolve, reject;

    const fetchItems = _.debounce(() => {
      console.log('fetching items...');
      const currentResolve = resolve;
      const currentReject = reject;
      const currentIdsToFetch = idsToFetch;

      Promise.resolve(fetchFunc(currentIdsToFetch))
        .then(res => currentResolve(res))
        .catch(err => currentReject(err));

      getItemsPromise = resolve = reject = null;
      idsToFetch = [];
    }, debounceTime);

    const getItems = (ids) => {
      idsToFetch = ids.filter((id) => !idsToFetch.includes(id)).concat(idsToFetch);
      if (!getItemsPromise) {
        getItemsPromise = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
          resolve = _resolve;
          reject = _reject;
        });
      }
      const currentPromise = getItemsPromise;
      fetchItems();

      return currentPromise
        .then((res) => {
          return res.filter((item) => ids.includes(item.id));
        })
    }

    return getItems;
  }

  const getItems = makeGetter((ids) => {
    // simulating ajax request
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        const result = ids.map((id) => fakeData.find(item => item.id == id));
        resolve(result);
      }, 400);
    })
  });


  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('first request start');
    getItems([1]).then(res => console.log('first result:', res));
  }, 100);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('second request start');
    getItems([1, 2]).then(res => console.log('second result:', res));
  }, 200)
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('third request start');
    getItems([1, 3]).then(res => console.log('third result:', res));
  }, 300)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Should be possible without having to externalize `resolve` and `reject`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Please feel free to add an answer showing how.